# How to print multiple Excel tabs to multiple PDF files?

Tags: pdf

Is it possible to select multiple tabs in Excel and print, or save them to multiple PDF files.

Meaning, one PDF file per tab. At the moment multiple tabs are combined on the one PDF file when printed.

Comment: It will be complicated to do what you want.  It is easier to simply split the pdf into seperate files for each page after printing/saving.

Answer (score 1):

In the save area where you choose your format, in this case pdf, you can choose 'workbook' which is all tabs, or 'sheet' which is the active tab.

I use 'automator' (on mac but there would be something similar on other platforms i'm sure). That 'automator' software splits multiple page pdf's into single page pdf's and saves them to the chosen destination volume/folder.

Simple multi-tab/page excel pdf's might not be worth that small effort but once the tab count in Excel gets substantial the use of that automator or similar software is a great help with many more functions.